# How to use a Service to populate Entity fields in a Form? (via query_builder)

Tags: forms, symfony, query-builder

In my Symfony2 projects I always use "Manager Services" to decouple all the model layer. (e.g. WorldManagerService, UserManagerService, etc...)

The problem is that I do not know how to use those Services for fill my entity fields inside Forms (e.g. Language combobox field in a form)

the code:

```
$builder->add('idlanguage', 'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Language',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => '',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository)
        {
            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('l')
                ->where('l.idstatus = :status')
                ->setParameter('status', '1');
        }
    ));
```

then, having the service declared in my project:

```
services:
    my.world.manager:
        class: %my_world.manager_service.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

I want to do something like:

```
$builder->add('idlanguage', 'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Language',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => '',
        'query_builder' => function (WorldManagerService $wms)
        {
            return $wms->getAllActiveLanguages();
        }
    ));
```

considering that normally I need to inject or invoke (using container class) the services, I do not know how to do here.

**How to fill form entities using Services?**

Comment: Maybe, if you want to move into this direction, it is wise to consider a FormFactory service where you inject what you need. This FormFactory now can instantiate things correctly (passing, perhaps your `wms`)

Comment: @DonCallisto do you know any online example or guide to do that?

Comment: no, I don't. Read something about Dependency Injection on Symfony2 guide.